# Authentication required, please use "web_set_user" solution not working

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I'm trying loadRunner (Vugen) 12.53. I recorded a very simple navigation to HP Web Tours App. This simplest navigation (site opens up in the browser) gives me the following error while replaying:

> Authentication required, please use "web_set_user", e.g. web_set_user("domain\user", "password", "host:port");   [MsgId: MERR-26547]

I'm very new to loadRunner.  Hence, I used web_set_user at the beginning of the editor as:

```
 web_set_user("localhost\\jojo", "bean", "localhost:1080");
```

I tried enabling "WinInet" at runtime setting but no luck. HP VuGEN Help Center does not seem to address this common issue in their guide.

Comment: why the heck are you guys downvoting for nothing !!! I edited the question a long ago

Comment: Try not to worry about downvotes - it's only two. I explained why I downvoted in an earlier comment (now deleted). If someone else wished to explain their downvote they could have done, but if they did not then don't worry about it - just remember to put a bit more effort into your future questions. I am confused when you say you edited the question - I can't see that you did. Instead I had to edit it, to make it readable.

Comment: I m also confused bcoz I myself posted the edited version of urs. U did the editing n I let it to be posted here again. But thank you for the reminder. I have still a lot to know about stack policy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this line does nothing:

```
web_set_user("localhost\\jojo", "bean", "localhost:1080");
```

You are trying to use a user for local host but that doesnt make any sense.

Your error message can come from 2 places:

1. The site requires authentication.
2. You are behind a proxy which requires authentication.

If you are using a proxy server under run-time settings, please fill in your user and password for proxy authentication.

If you are not using a proxy, you need to provide **the remote site** your password, not localhost. try changing the web_set_user command to:

```
web_set_user("<domain name>\\<user in domain>", "<password>", "<site address server name>:80");
```

or

```
web_set_user("<domain name>\\<user in domain>", "<password>", "<site address server name>:8080");
```

For example:

```
web_set_user("IAN_Net\\james", "bobo1", "MercuryTours.com:8080");
web_set_user("IAN_Net\\james", "bobo1", "localserver:8080");
web_set_user("IAN_Net\\james", "bobo1", "10.2.33.222:8080");
web_set_user("IAN_Net\\james", "bobo1", "10.2.33.222:80");
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank u very much. BUT it didnt solve anything.I m using the local server for HP Web Tours App. Hence I used " web_set_user("localhost\\jojo", "bean", "localhost:1080"); " I dont use ANY PROXY. I used the same web_set_user(..) as u described above. I m totally out of mind now !! Stuck here for a few days. What is my domain name in case of local server? is it my host name? I used "localhost"

Comment: try computername\\username

Comment: and why port 1080 ?

Comment: I tried my computer name and the latest Web Tours App uses port 1080, nothing worked for web_set_user () . I can easily navigate to http://127.0.0.1:1080/WebTours/index.htm in browser. I m fed up now. I guess this problem has something to do with unnecessary traffic sent by chrome browser to googleapi, which has nothing to do with my Web Tour login process. Hence, I filtered out traffic for " *.googleapis.com " . I also set "network level interception for any server at port 1080 via trapping" in port mapping. Now after I record a simple business process (log-in ), it plays well without error.

Comment: But if I record another end-to-end process (searching,booking a flight ), it always end up showing an error for  Error -27979: Requested form not found  [MsgId: MERR-27979] . Do u have any idea how I can master this VuGen Code, I have no idea whatsoever about this descriptive language. I m also not happy with this work-around, bypassing the googleapi domain was not a wishful choice for me. I still wonder why web_set_user("localhost\\jojo", "bean", "localhost:1080"); didnt work. I also tried web_set_user("MyMachineName\\jojo", "bean", "localhost:1080"); to no avail..

Comment: In runtime settings, what is defined under "Proxy" ?

Comment: In runtime setting- NO PROXY , since I dont use any proxy and proxy recording is not used

Comment: Can you give me the line in the script that gives you the error ?

Comment: As I said Above, I have already bypassed the authentication problem with Traffic Filtering for googlapi.com.  Now, after I record a simple end-to-end business process, it always gives me - 
Action.c(90): web_submit_form("reservations.pl_2") started   [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(90): Error -27979: Requested form not found   [MsgId: MERR-27979]
Action.c(90): web_submit_form("reservations.pl_2") highest severity level was "ERROR", 0 body bytes, 0 header bytes   [MsgId: MMSG-26388]

Comment: So that is a **Whole different issue** - First, accept my asnwer for this question as correct, and then open a new question with the updated data and post the question link here, so we can resolve it as a new question.

Comment: hmm but web_set_user("MymachineName\\jojo", "bean", "localhost:1080") DID NOT WORK, AS I SAID BEFORE. I had to bypass that with traffic filtering for googleapi. But I can revert back to that problem again n see if ur solution may help.