# Web_set_user in Loadrunner not working and browser not configured for using SPNego

Tags: browser, loadrunner, spnego

I have an issue on my script where I run the script and it gives me this error:

> Authentication required, please use "web_set_user", e.g. web_set_user("domain\user", "password", "host:port");   [MsgId: MERR-26547]
>
> [image]

Given that error, I tried to add this web_set_user on my script and still not working.

[image]

Also other than that, when I check the replay, it shows this error:

> Your browser is not configured for using SPNego
>
> [image]

I tried configuring everything from IE browser to Loadrunner but still no luck.

SAPNego: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_SPNEGO_configweb_new.html
Web_set_user: [Authentication required, please use "web_set_user" solution not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572426/authentication-required-please-use-web-set-user-solution-not-working)

Would anyone please help me if you did encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run time browser is not a full featured browser.  I would not expect it to render a modern framework correctly

Make sure wininet is elected with web_set_user()

Have you considered Truclient?

Comment: Hi James, so you mean, the value that is being shown in the replay may not be right? or can you please elaborate. 
We haven't considered using Truclient, because these scripts are working fine the last time, it's just that after the SAP refresh and the Server went to hibernate state, that's where our scripts are not working anymore.

Comment: The run time display is not a full featured browser.  You should not ever expect it to render the same way as IE, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, ... will.   The logs are accurate.  "Server went to hibernate state...."   I would be checking your scripts for any unhandled session or time based items that need to be correlated/parameterized

Comment: Thanks James, this issue is fixed. It's just because of a cookie, so we just added a header to handle that cookie and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This is already resolved. We just add a header which is a cookie and it works fine now. Thank you.